# How find all documents in elasticsearch that matches with fields and values?

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I have an index `users` with `user` type. Mapping is dynamic. For now `user` hs a following structure:

```
"user": {
        "nested": {
            "one":51
        },
        "other": {
            "two":"hi!"
        },
        "three":false
    }
```

I need to find all users which has `other.two` field with value `hi` or has `three` field with value `false`. E.g. user which has `other.two` must have `hi` value in it or `three` field with value `false`. How to select this from elastic search?

I have tried:

```
GET /users/user/_search
{"query": {"match": {"other.two": "hi"}}}
```

Returns a user for me, but

```
GET /users/user/_search
    {"query": {"match": {"other.two": "hi", "three":false}}}
```

Returns me a `SearchPhaseExecutionException`.

How combine several fields and values for searching?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Bool filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html) or [Bool Query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Answer (score 2):

As @rvheddeg suggested above, here is the query that works for me:

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
                { "match": { "other.two":  "hi" }},
                { "match": { "three": false  }}
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
    }
}
```